# How to print a script's source in unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a custom script in one of the $PATH folders. I know its a plaintext python script and not a compiled binary. Is there any way to print the source?

I have tried `whereis <scriptname>`, but that doesn't return anything.

```
$>ls -lrt `echo $PATH | sed "s/:/\n /g"` | grep <scriptname>
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root eng  30 Oct 16  2011 <scriptname> -> ../depot/dcs-scripts/bin/<scriptname>
```

What does a `../` mean in  `../depot/dcs-scripts/bin/<scriptname>`?

Comment: Could the downvoters please give a reason?

Comment: `..` in a path means to go up to the parent directory.

Comment: The `whereis` command looks only in standard places for commands; your command is probably not in a standard place so it is not found by `whereis`.  Using `which` works with your PATH, so it will find things that `whereis` doesn't (though if you've removed standard places from your PATH, `whereis` may find things that `which` doesn't).  As to the `..`, that means that the script is a symlink to a file that is not actually in the directory on your path but in another directory.  If it was found in `/home/you/bin`, the file is actually in `/home/depot/dcs-scripts/bin/` instead.

Comment: I know the `../` means the parent directory, but what confused me was that I was running it from `/home/you/bin` but there was no directory as `/home/depots/dcs-scripts/bin` . I realize now that `../` will refer to the directory 1 level above where the actual script resides.
Also, this question better suits [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat `which scriptname`
```

Usually does the trick